# mod_rewrite: QSA flag breaks configuration

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have this rewrite rule for a webservice:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^service/(.*)$ blabla/service.php?request=$1 [L]
```

It's working fine, but now I need to append the query string and found the QSA flag. I added it next to the L, but it seems to break mod_rewrite, because I get a 500 from Apache and my php script is not reached.

```
RewriteRule ^service/(.*)$ blabla/service.php?request=$1 [QSA, L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

...it seems that mod_rewrite doesn't like white spaces between flags.

```
RewriteRule ^service/(.*)$ blabla/service.php?request=$1 [QSA,L]
                                                             ^
```

This fixed the problem (sigh).